# Get Categories (multiple levels)

Tags: php

I am making a script which will load all categories from a database. I just don't know how I can do this in a way which is shorter.
I am trying to figure out a way in which I can theoretically load infinite levels of categories.

```
$stmt1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Hoofdrubriek IS NULL");
while($row1 = $db->fetch($stmt1))
{
    $stmt2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Hoofdrubriek = '" . $row1['Rubrieknummer'] . "'");
    while($row2 = $db->fetch($stmt2))
    {


        $stmt3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Hoofdrubriek = '" . $row2['Rubrieknummer'] . "'");
        while($row3 = $db->fetch($stmt3))
        {


            $stmt4 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Hoofdrubriek = '" . $row3['Rubrieknummer'] . "'");
            while($row4 = $db->fetch($stmt4))
            {
                $row3['CATEGORY3'][] = array(
                    'CATEGORY4_NAME'    => ucfirst(strtolower($row4['Rubrieknaam'])),
                );
            }

            $row2['CATEGORY3'][] = array(
                'CATEGORY3_NAME'    => ucfirst(strtolower($row3['Rubrieknaam'])),
                'CATEGORY4'         => $row2['CATEGORY4'],
            );
        }

        $row1['CATEGORY2'][] = array(
            'CATEGORY2_NAME'    => ucfirst(strtolower($row2['Rubrieknaam'])),
            'CATEGORY3'         => $row2['CATEGORY3'],
        );
    }

    $catagories[] = array(
        'CATEGORY_NAME' => ucfirst(strtolower($row1['Rubrieknaam'])),
        'CATEGORY2'     => $row1['CATEGORY2'],      
    );      
}
```

I would like to have some ideas on how to make this happen.
(I am using a little template system that processes the array that is being made)

EDIT:

Thanks to Ivijan Stefan Stipić I was able to solve this.
This is what I ended up doing

```
$categories = build_category(0);
```

And the function:

```
function build_category($parent, $row = NULL)
{
    global $db;

    // Initialise array
    $data = array();

    // Basic SQL statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Rubriek";

    // Where condition based on $row
    if(is_null($row))
    {
        $where = " WHERE Hoofdrubriek IS NULL";
    }
    else 
    {
        $where = " WHERE Hoofdrubriek = '" . $row['Rubrieknummer'] . "'";
    }

    // Execute query
    $stmt = $db->query($sql . $where);

    // Next level parent
    $next = $parent + 1;

    // Fetch results
    while($row = $db->fetch($stmt))
    {
        $data[] = array(
            'CATEGORY' . $parent . '_NAME'  => ucfirst(strtolower($row['Rubrieknaam'])),
            'CATEGORY' . $next              => build_category($next, $row),
        );
    }

    // Return data
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. I like your version, it is much more dynamic. I'm happy to help and next time. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about this solution?

```
function next_level($val)
{
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Rubrieknummer != '" .$val. "' AND Hoofdrubriek = '" .$val. "'");

    while($row = $db->fetch($stmt))
    {
        echo ucfirst(strtolower($row['Rubrieknaam']));
        echo next_level($row['Rubrieknummer']);
    }
}


$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Rubriek WHERE Hoofdrubriek IS NULL");
while($row = $db->fetch($stmt))
{
    echo ucfirst(strtolower($row['Rubrieknaam']));
    echo next_level($row['Rubrieknummer']);
}
```

If I understand correctly this is the number of categories with unlimited subcategories.

Comment: Hmmm good one, this might actually work. I am going to try thgis out.

Comment: I wrote from memory, I might have made ​​a mistake. This is the best way for me. But you'd better do one class so that you have lighten orientation.